# How to scrape and count star rating using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently trying to scrape the reviews on this particular website: https://shopee.sg/buyer/275295198/rating but am unable to figure out a way using selenium to scrape star ratings since each star is an svg on its own. Realized that there's a pattern between filled stars and unfilled stars:

This is the current code i have for counting and summing the filled stars, but seem to only return 1:

```
    # Star rating
      star_ratings = product.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='shopee-product-rating__rating']")
      stars = product.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='shopee-svg-icon icon-rating-solid--active icon-rating-solid']")

      star_rate = 0
      for rating in star_ratings:
          #print(rating.get_attribute('svg'))
          if (product.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='shopee-svg-icon icon-rating-solid--active icon-rating-solid']")) == stars:
              star_rates = star_rate + 1
              continue
      rating_csv.append(star_rates)
      print(star_rates)
```

Comment: I think better if you use `find_elements_by_class_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `len()` of `stars` to get the info, without iterating over the result and count, if it only covers the active stars:

```
rating_csv.append(len(stars))
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://shopee.sg/buyer/208830993/rating'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

for rating in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.shopee-product-rating'):
    stars = rating.find_elements_by_css_selector('.icon-rating-solid')
    print(len(stars))
    
driver.close()
```

**Output**

```
4
5
5
5
5
5
```